# visualizing document similarity points

Tags: java, algorithm, document, similarity

We are currently doing a project on plagiarism detection of two text document. We have to compare two submitted documents and present the comparison results. For that I want to present the two documents side by side and highlight the similarity points between the documents in a GUI. I used various algorithms to get the similarity score between two documents such as vector space and shingle cloud algorithms. but they dont provide the sections that have the similarity and I have to present them to the user where the similarity occurs in a graphical interface.

Thanx
Nuwan

Comment: and your specific question is?

Comment: How can I graphically(not in charts but the similarity areas should be highlighted)  represent the similarity areas? And what are the approaches(algoritms on indexing words with positions) to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it really be graphical? You're comparing text. It seems like you'd want to stick with a textual interface. However, you could create something pretty quickly with Swing. I'd probably start by printing out the shingles that the documents share in common along with some context. I also tried searching for some off-the-shelf diff engine you could use but came up short. Maybe you could actually somehow shell out to or somehow incorporate the Unix `diff` tool into your application?